# Javascript module pattern : calling functions within nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have code like that :

```
var SEVERINU = SEVERINU || {};

SEVERINU.AutoGallery = {
    galleryImagesNames: new Array(),

    findImages: function () {
        var dirToResearch = this.galleryName;

        $.post(
            "_php/get-files.php", {
            dir: dirToResearch,
            ext: this.fileExtension
        }, function (data) {
            var pliki = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in pliki) {
                this.galleryImagesNames.push(pliki[i]); // problem !
            }
        });

    },
}
```

This line: `this.galleryImagesNames.push(pliki[i]);` is giving me problems.

It says he cant find that var galleryImagesNames etc.

How to call functions, var if I am to 'deep' ?

Comment: The context (`this`) has changed, `this` is no longer what you think it is inside that callback.

Comment: so how to call galleryImagesNames ?

Comment: See any of the existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just save current `this` to some other variable so it won't get overwritten inside the function.

```
var SEVERINU = SEVERINU || {};

SEVERINU.AutoGallery = {
  galleryImagesNames : new Array(),

  findImages : function(){
        var self = this; // keep current value of this in variable named self
        var dirToResearch = this.galleryName;

        $.post(
            "_php/get-files.php",
            {
                dir: dirToResearch,
                ext: this.fileExtension
            },
            function(data){
                var pliki = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
                for(var i in pliki){
                    // call the method using self variable instead of this that got overwritten
                    self.galleryImagesNames.push(pliki[i]); 
                }
            }
        );

    },

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's because your `$.post` has a different scope than the rest of the object. Try this:

```
findImages : function(){
    var dirToResearch = this.galleryName;
    var gImageNames = this.galleryImagesNames;
    $.post(
        "_php/get-files.php",
        {
            dir: dirToResearch,
            ext: this.fileExtension
        },
        function(data){
            var pliki = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
            for(var i in pliki){
                gImageNames.push(pliki[i]); // we have access to this variable
            }
        }
    );

},
```

Comment: it returns empty array . array looks good until within $.post , after ... it is totally empty. can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inside an anonymous function you will have to reference the `this` keyword again. Or use it directly like so:

```
SEVERINU.AutoGallery.galleryImagesNames.push(pliki[i]);
```

Usually when you need the reference `SEVERINU.AutoGallery` more than once you better store it in a variable like:

```
var that = SEVERINU.AutoGallery; // or "self" or something you prefer

for (var i in pliki) {
    that.galleryImagesNames.push(pliki[i]);
}
```

The reason for this is because javascript tends to be slow when accessing object namespaces. The deeper you go the slower it gets. The more references you make, the slower it will become since function scope has to be resolved first in order to access the next/previous scope.

Comment: this one worked for me but wanted to use this , in case if somebody will change part SEVERINU.Autogallery to something else. Thanks

Comment: Especially in your for loop you will access `SEVERINU.AutoGallery` as many times as the length of your object. When stored in a variable it will be referenced and more performant. The same goes for jquery selectors for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass in the context.

```
var SEVERINU = SEVERINU || {};

SEVERINU.AutoGallery = {
 galleryImagesNames : new Array(),

 findImages : function(){
    var dirToResearch = this.galleryName;

    $.post(
        "_php/get-files.php",
        {
            dir: dirToResearch,
            ext: this.fileExtension
        },
        $.proxy(function(data){ //Set up for the context to be passes for this function.
            var pliki = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
            for(var i in pliki){
                this.galleryImagesNames.push(pliki[i]); // problem solved. now this doesn't refer to ajax context
            }
        },this) <-- Pass the context here
    );

},
}
```

> $.proxy Takes a function and returns a new one that will always have a particular context.